# What characters are valid in a URL?

Tags: html, url

I'm trying to remove the non-URL part of a big string. Most of the regexes I found are like `[A-Za-z0-9-_.!~*'()]`, but there are more things that can a url contain. Like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test?v=123#this` for example

So what are the latest characters for a valid URL?

Comment: Have you looked at the RFC? http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html

Comment: There's what's technically a valid URL and what's actually used as a URL today.  Only 25% of the internet is even written in English.  #2 and #4 languages are Chinese and Arabic.  This answer to another question sums it up nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36667242/1128668

Answer (score 167):

All the gory details can be found in the current RFC on the topic:  [RFC 3986 (Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

Based on [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid/1547940#1547940), you are looking at a list that looks like: `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `-`, `.`, `_`, `~`, `:`, `/`, `?`, `#`, `[`, `]`, `@`, `!`, `$`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `;`, `%`, and `=`.  Everything else must be [url-encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).  Also, some of these characters can only exist in very specific spots in a URI and outside of those spots must be url-encoded (e.g. `%` can only be used in conjunction with url encoding as in `%20`), the RFC has all of these specifics.

Comment: Note: this list doesn't include the percent sign

Comment: That is correct @thomasrutter, a % is used for url-encoding.  A % needs to be represented as %25 to be used in a URI.

From the RFC:
Because the percent ("%") character serves as the indicator for percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as "%25" for that octet to be used as data within a URI.

Comment: Just to mention that some of those ('/','?','#','&','+') while valid, serve particular functionality in a URL with query component and are not treated as just regular chars

Comment: `http://example.com/hello%20world` is a valid URL, therefore the character `%` is valid in a URL and should be in the list.

Comment: @MartinJambon FYI, I gave a response on that exact comment above already.

Comment: @ckittel your response is at best ambiguous. Would you like to clarify what you think is correct? The question is what characters are valid in a URL. It's not asking which characters need to be escaped. Other characters than `%`, such as `/`, have a special meaning and need to be escaped for them to be part e.g. of path component data; but it's not the question.

Comment: A shorter summary (if I didn't make any mistakes):  Valid values are the range '!' to 'z', except double quote ", backslash \, caret ^, less than <, greater than >, and backtick `.

Comment: @ckittel, what does the symbol ';' mean in a URL?

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul - nothing different than any other character.  For example, I might do https://example.org/search?facets=cat1:red;cat2:xl -- really it would be up the the application to decide what meaning to make from that character.

Comment: ah ok. I thought it is something like the ? and & where you pass parameters together with the URL.

Comment: `/[A-Za-z0-9-._~:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;%=]+/g`

Comment: @yeah22, you can skip the escape before the first "[". Updated version: `/[A-Za-z0-9-._~:/?#[\]@!$&'()*+,;%=]+/g`