# Regex to detect a string that contains a URL or file extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a small script that detects whether the string input is either:

1) a URL (which will hold a filename): 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/html5shiv.js'

2) just a filename: 'html5shiv.js'

So far I've found this but I think it just checks the URL and file extension. Is there an easy way to make it so it uses an 'or' check? I'm not very experienced with RegExp.

```
var myRegExp = /[^\\]*\.(\w+)$/i;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, to use 'OR' in regex, simply use the 'pipe' delimiter.

```
(aaa|bbb)
```

will match

```
aaa
```

or

```
bbb
```

For regex to match a url, I'd suggest the following:

```
\w+://[\w\._~:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%]*
```

This is based on the [allowed character set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url) for a url.

For the file, what's your definition of a filename?

If you want to search for strings, that match "(at least) one to many non-fullstop characters, followed by a fullstop, followed by (at least) one to many non-fullstop characters", I'd suggest the following regex:

```
[^\.]+\.[^\.]+
```

And altogether:

```
(\w+://[\w\._~:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=%]*|[^\.]+\.[^\.]+)
```

Here's an example of working (in javascript): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tNX7N/2/)

You can test it out regex online here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Why is there no `%` in the URL regex?

Comment: Great question! The answer is I was lazy and just ripped the valid characters straight from this answer (should've done my homework properly) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url#7109208 ! I've updated the answer to include '%'.

Answer (score 2):

How bout this regex?

```
(\.js)$
```

it checks the end of the line if it has a .js on it.

`$` denotes end of line.

[tested here.](http://rubular.com/r/JEv1RYN4fB)

Comment: `\.` instead of `.` though.

Answer (score 1):

If it is for the purpose of flow control you can do the following:

```
var test = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/html5shiv.js";    

// to recognize http & https
var regex = /^https?:\/\/.*/i;    
var result = regex.exec(test);    
if (result == null){
    // no URL found code
} else {
    // URL found code
}
```

For the purpose of capturing the file name you could use:

```
var test = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/html5shiv.js";    

var regex = /(\w+\.\w+)$/i;    
var filename = regex.exec(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this (requires no regex at all):

```
var filename = string.indexOf('/') == -1
             ? string
             : string.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
```

Comment: Very cool. I'm reusing a different RegEx, as I actually use .test() on it before this function call to return the boolean on whether it has a file at all.

Comment: Okay, didn't know you need to use regex. But why the downvote?

Comment: `Array` doesn't have a method `last()` in any current ES spec. I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the alternation operator `|`.  Be careful, though, because its priority is very low.  Lower than sequencing.  You will need to write things like `/(cat)|(dog)/`.

It's very hard to understand what you exactly want with so few use/test cases, but

```
(http://[a-zA-Z0-9\./]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)
```

should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a URL, strip it down to the last part and treat it the same way as "just a filename".

```
function isFile(fileOrUrl) {
    // This will return everything after the last '/'; if there's
    // no forward slash in the string, the unmodified string is used
    var filename = fileOrUrl.split('/').pop();
    return (/.+\..+/).test(filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ajx = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/html5shiv.js';
function isURL(str){
  return /((\/\w+)|(^\w+))\.\w{2,}$/.test(str);
}
console.log(isURL(ajx));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program!

```
<script>
var url="Home/this/example/file.js";
var condition=0;
var result="";
for(var i=url.length; i>0 && condition<2 ;i--)
{
    if(url[i]!="/" && url[i]!="."){result= (condition==1)? (url[i]+result):(result);}
    else{condition++;}
}
document.write(result);
</script>
```