# php domdocument loadhtml turns $ into (url encoding)%24 unexpectedly

Tags: php, domdocument

for this php script,

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->substituteEntities =FALSE;
    $dom->loadHTML('<a href="$a?">$a</a>');
    // print_r ($dom->getElementsByTagName("a")->item(0)->getAttribute("href"));
```

//the above statement show $a? correctly

```
    echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

but it returned <a href="%24a">$a</a> to the browser when a saveHTML method was called.
The $ in the href attribute was turned into %24 whereas the $ in the content of the a tag remains unchanged.

I expect the output is <a href="$a">$a</a>
Is there any way to do this aside from the replace method?

By the way,

```
  echo $dom->saveXML();
```

I get what I want with saveXML();
but together with an unexpected <!--xml......
Thanks

Comment: Well, [`$` is not valid in a url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url). Any special reason you want to keep an invalid href?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is due to the requirement of a web service. they use $XXX as a variable to inject their script on it.

Comment: Hm, yeah, so 'not-quite-html-but-almost' it is.. Tricky indeed.  If the HTML snippet doesn't contain content that would make it deviate from `XML` standards, an alternative to the accepted answer is saving a node instead of the while document to prevent the xml prologue by saving it like `$dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);`, but that has it's own quircks & drawbacks. The current one would have as drawback that if you _need_ something urlencoded you'd have to double encode it. So, take your pick as to what suits you better ;)

Comment: Same problem here. The loadHTML method automatically and unwantedly decodes url's in metatags. For instance a canonical. So after using this method the canonical on this URL http://mathsgenius.co.za/qa/961/solve-%24x-2-2x-1-0%24 was decoded into  http://mathsgenius.co.za/qa/961/solve-$x-2-2x-1-0$

The source of the HTML contains the correct canonical URL.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can wrap echo in [urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to solve this issue :

```
echo urldecode($dom->saveHTML());
```

Comment: What if `urldecode` decodes characters that don't have to?

Comment: urldecode should only be done at specific parts like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448119/how-can-i-prevent-html-entities-with-php-a-domdocumentsavehtml

Answer (score 1):

A safer approach in my case was to use:

```
$dom->saveXML();
```