# java valid regex for any url starting with my domain, protocol, view and the rest of the url

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex string to match URL starting with "https" "www.mydomain.com", "myView?" "rest of the url"
The regex is for use in the jsf views no for code.

**Valid urls:**

```
https://www.mydomain.com/myView?z
https://www.mydomain.com/myView?a=hello&b=world&c=how&d=are&e=you
https://www.mydomain.com/myView?a=hello&b=world&c=how&d=are&e=(you)
```

**Invalid urls:**

```
https://www.mydomain.com/myView?
https://www.mydomain.com/myView
https://www.mydomain.com/myViewfdgdfgfd
```

**Test code:**

```
//Pattern to check if this is a valid URL address, not work
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(https://www.mydomain.com/myView?)");
Matcher m;
m=p.matcher(urlAddress);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Doesn't seem like you put much effort into it. You should really look into regex.. And for no effort shown (this is a code request), -1

Comment: Any effort from your end.?

Comment: Also, [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class already implements all the logic required to parse URL's. Consider using that instead of regular expressions.

Comment: You practically wrote most of the regex yourself. Add a start anchor, escape the metacharacters and use `\S+` after the `?`

Comment: You also never mention if the regex should account for `www`

Comment: Use the `URI` class; it makes this kind of tests much easier.

Comment: the regex is for use in the views no for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple case. This only have two parts, the start of the expression and the rest.

**Start expression:**

```
^https://www.mydomain.com/myView\\?
```

**Rest of the url ([Valid url chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url)):**

```
[a-zA-Z0-9~!';@#\\^\\$%&\\*\\(\\)-_\\+=\\[\\]\\{\\}\\|\\\\,\\.\\?\\s]
```

**Test code:**

```
    String regex = "^https://www.mydomain.com/myView\\?[a-zA-Z0-9~!';@#\\^\\$%&\\*\\(\\)-_\\+=\\[\\]\\{\\}\\|\\\\,\\.\\?\\s]+";

    String validUrlchars = "[a-zA-Z0-9~!';@#\\^\\$%&\\*\\(\\)-_\\+=\\[\\]\\{\\}\\|\\\\,\\.\\?\\s]";

    String url1 = "https://www.mydomain.com/myView?z";
    String url2 = "https://www.mydomain.com/myView?";
    String url3 = "https://www.mydomain.com/myView";
    String url4 = "https://www.mydomain.com/myViewfdgdfgfd";
    String url5 = "https://www.mydomain.com/myView?a=hello&b=world&c=how&d=are&e=you";
    String url6 = "https://www.mydomain.com/myView?a=hello&b=world&c=how&d=are&e=(you)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m;
    m = p.matcher(url1);
    System.out.println(m.matches() + " " + url1);
    m = p.matcher(url2);
    System.out.println(m.matches() + " " + url2);
    m = p.matcher(url3);
    System.out.println(m.matches() + " " + url3);
    m = p.matcher(url4);
    System.out.println(m.matches() + " " + url4);
    m = p.matcher(url5);
    System.out.println(m.matches() + " " + url5);
    m = p.matcher(url6);
    System.out.println(m.matches() + " " + url6);
```

**Output:**

```
true https://www.mydomain.com/myView?z
false https://www.mydomain.com/myView?
false https://www.mydomain.com/myView
false https://www.mydomain.com/myViewfdgdfgfd
true https://www.mydomain.com/myView?a=hello&b=world&c=how&d=are&e=you
true https://www.mydomain.com/myView?a=hello&b=world&c=how&d=are&e=(you)
```