# CSharp: Uri.IsWellFormedUriString return true wrongfully

Tags: c#

Why

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://www.foo@foo.com", UriKind.Absolute);
```

return **true** ?!

Can we use **@** in a website domain?!!!

Comment: See this question for details on which characters are allowed in a `url`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's optional and can be used for authentication more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The part before the @ sign is the username.

Comment: Thank you dear friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can.

If you put this url in your browser, it will warn you (at least my firefox does so) that you are trying to authenticate with `foo.com` as user `www%2Efoo`.

The `@` is used to separate user credentials from the address. This is rarely used with http, but more often with ftp: `ftp://user:password@domain.com`.

Comment: Thank you dear friend :)