# hyphen makes error in file_get_contents php

Tags: php, json, url, yii

I have an api in one of my sites. When I try to fetch contents width `file_get_contents` an error occures.
I have tested the url in the browser and it's okay.
Here is my url `dilox.ir/category/مجله-ماشین/?json=1` and here is my php code

```
$cat = 'مجله-ماشین';
$json = file_get_contents('http://dilox.ir/category/' . $cat . '/json=1&count=10&page=' . $page);
```

after I execute my code. I face with this error

```
{ "name":"PHP Notice",
  "message":"Trying to get property of non-object",
  "code":8,
  "type":"yii\\base\\ErrorException",
  "file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pkhodro\\controllers\\ApiController.php",
  "line":142,
  "stack-trace":["#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pkhodro\\controllers\\ApiController.php(142): yii\\base\\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', 'C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', 142, Array)",
                "#1 [internal function]: app\\controllers\\ApiController->actionGet_magazines(1)",
                "#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pkhodro\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\InlineAction.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)",
                "#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pkhodro\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Controller.php(154): yii\\base\\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)",
                "#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pkhodro\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Module.php(454): yii\\base\\Controller->runAction('get_magazines', Array)",
                "#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pkhodro\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\web\\Application.php(87): yii\\base\\Module->runAction('api/get_magazin...', Array)",
                "#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pkhodro\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Application.php(375): yii\\web\\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\\web\\Request))",
                "#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pkhodro\\web\\index.php(12): yii\\base\\Application->run()","#8 {main}"
                ]
}
```

it shows that it can't read the url. Same code is executing successfully for a category without hyphen

**Please see this Edit**

I tested my code. `file_get_contents` return json for me, but json_decode can't decode the returned json and cause the error

Comment: That is a PHP error, read it and fix the error

Comment: Yes , of course. But what error? @RiggsFolly As you see this link is shown in browser properly

Comment: It tells you, you are accessing a property of a non-object, so something is not an object that should be.  This would be a good place to look `ApiController.php",  "line":142,`

Comment: I see. but when I change my current category to a category without hyphen it work okay :( @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: I don't know Yii, but I assume these Categories are in a database? if so does the category exist.  It's typical for some queries to return false when there are no results instead of an object.

Comment: It's very strange for me, here is url which I call in the code `http://dilox.ir/category/مجله-ماشین/?json=1&count=10&page=1` and I can see this in browser but file_get_content can not read this :-| @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: please see the edit @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: Obviously that's not English, but I would say make sure the - is in the proper character set, I have very limited knowledge of foreign languages and how that affects the file system.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url