# $_GET automatically adding '_' to variable name?

Tags: php

I am checking whether a record exists in database or not

```
if ($row["count(*)"] == 0) {
    header('Location: first.php? stat = "not found"');
}
```

Now, to check the stat variable in first.php, I am doing -

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Output to this is -

```
Array ( [stat_] => "not found" )
```

I dont understand how 'stat' variable became 'stat_' variable ?

Comment: `php? stat` if that's your real code, remove the space for it `php?stat`

Comment: header('Location: first.php?stat =not%20found");

Comment: That location URL you try to use in your call to the `header()` function is invalid. You cannot have blanks in a URL. It is up to the client side to _try to_ make sense of that, unpredictable behavior is the result.

Comment: this is a classic typo/off-topic question and I can't emphasize on that enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the spaces in your `header` call:

```
header('Location: first.php?stat=not+found');
```

Comment: ah... c'mon, it's a typo.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It seems OP doesn't understand the effects spaces will have and is merely trying to write readable code.

Comment: Sure, I agree but we've all commented on it up there. The question should be closed as such; a typo.

Comment: I'm leaving the question now. Should you get a downvote (which I hope you won't), it would not have come from me. Btw, I hope the OP hasn't chased you down a rabbit hole here ;-)