# How To make Validation URL contain foreign language Like Arabic symbols with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

How To make Validation URL  contain foreign language  Like Arabic symbols with Laravel 
Like this 
[https://www.dott.com/news/1061/صاحب-السمو-يدشن-مصفاة-لفان-2](https://www.dott.com/news/1061/%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%85%D9%88-%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%B4%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%A9-%D9%84%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%86-2)

Comment: for me it worked very well -even for arabic- without any special needs. if you've any errors, exceptions, etc... please add it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out:

If you don't believe me then do a "View source in this question to verify that the URL is actually:

```
<a href="https://www.dott.com/news/1061/%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%AD%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%85%D9%88-%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%B4%D9%86-%D9%85%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%A9-%D9%84%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%86-2" rel="nofollow noreferrer">https://www.dott.com/news/1061/صاحب-السمو-يدشن-مصفاة-لفان-2</a>
```

You therefore need to do:

```
$url = urlencode("https://www.dott.com/news/1061/صاحب-السمو-يدشن-مصفاة-لفان-2");
```

However, if a browser gets a URL encoded string they are usually happy to translate the URL encoded symbols to characters and show them in the address bar.

As a reminder valid URL characters are:

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`.

Check
[What characters are valid in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url) or https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986 for more details.

Comment: Awesome, it works like a charm, but only changed the last section of the URL which output the post permalink as follow: `<?PHP echo $settings['siteurl'].'post/'.urlencode($post['permalink']); ?>`. Thank you so much.