# How to extract only the URL from the following strings using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am extracting URLs from a set of raw data and I intend to do this using python regular expressions.

I tried

```
(http.+)
```

But it just got the entire part starting from http.

**Input**

> href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone
>
> https://vine.co/v/i6iIrBwnTFI

**Expected Output**

> > http://twitter.com/download/iphone
> >
> > https://vine.co/v/i6iIrBwnTFI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `http[^\"^\s]*`

This assumes all your links will start with http and it will break the expression if it encounters a whitespace or a `"`

Here is how you could use it:

```
import re
regexp = '''http[^\"^\s]*'''
urls = '''href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone https://vine.co/v/i6iIrBwnTFI'''
output = re.findall(regexp, urls)
output
```

> ['http://twitter.com/download/iphone',
>   'https://vine.co/v/i6iIrBwnTFI']

Comment: Do you mean (http[^\"^\s]*)

Comment: Added some code that explains how you can use the regex

Answer (score 0):

First, u should find [what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url)

Then, the regular expression could be:

```
(http://|https://)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._~:/\?\#\[\]@!$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]+)
```

In my python interpreter, it looks like:

```
>>> import re
>>> regexp = '''(http://|https://)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._~:/\?\#\[\]@!$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]+)'''
>>> url = '''href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone https://vine.co/v/i6iIrBwnTFI'''
>>> r = re.findall(regexp, url)
>>> r
[('http://', 'twitter.com/download/iphone'), ('https://', 'vine.co/v/i6iIrBwnTFI')]
>>> [x[0]+x[1] for x in r]
['http://twitter.com/download/iphone', 'https://vine.co/v/i6iIrBwnTFI']
```