# Replace comma with special characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, string, replace

I have a requirement where I want to replace all occurrences of ',' with '\,'. It works if I try to replace with other characters/strings, but seems to have some issue with '\,'.

```
'http://example.com/pqr?xyz=11,22.html'.replace(/,/g, '\,')
```

I expect to get result as 'http://example.com/pqr?xyz=11\,22.html'.

Thanks in advance !!

**EDIT**

After trying couple of answers (use '\\,' instead of '\,'), I found that console.log is escaping \ i.e it is showing single slash instead of double slash. When I use this variable, it is considering double slash value.

I am seeing two different results when I use console log vs not using console.log.

[image]

Comment: In regex, the '\' char is used to escape other chars to make them literal. to make this char literal you need to escape it as well. `\\,`.

Comment: I don't know your use case, but "\" isn't a valid URL character unless it's properly encoded. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url).

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah.. I know adding  "\" will make it invalid URL, but I want to consider it as string. Actually my intention here is to escape comma, so to do that I wanted to add '\' before comma. I used URL in the example, but that will not always be use case.

Answer (score 0):

Will this be good enough? you need to escape the `\`

```js
console.log('http://example.com/pqr?xyz=11,22.html'.replace(/,/g, '\\,'))
```

Comment: console.log is printing the expected result, but when I tried it by assigning it to a variable and found that it is producing result with \\ (double slash) - "http://example.com/pqr?xyz=11\\,22.html"

Answer (score 0):

```js
let url ="http://example.com/pqr?xyz=11,22.html"
url = url.replace(',' , '\\,')
console.log(url)
```

Comment: console.log is printing the expected result, but when I tried it by assigning it to a variable and found that it is producing result with \\ (double slash) - "example.com/pqr?xyz=11\\,22.html"