# django app is not able to find a url using slugs

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls, slug

I have a simple blog app that has a blog home and the details.
I am using slug for detail URLs and prepopulating the slug field with the post title. everything works fine local but after I deployed the app online, when I click the post to go to its' blog detail it won't find the page.

this is my post models:

```
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return PostQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def search(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)

class Post(models.Model):
    objects = PostManager()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    paragraph = models.TextField(blank=True)
    published = jmodels.jDateField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

this is my urls:

```
path('maghaalaat/', views.MaghaleMain.as_view(), name="blog-page"),
path('maghaalaat/tags/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.MaghaleTags.as_view(), name="tagged"),
re_path(r'maghaalaat/(?P<the_slug>[-\w]+)/', views.MaghaleDetail.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
```

this is my views:

```
class MaghaleMain(ListView):
    model = MaghaalaatPost
    template_name = 'Blog/Blog-elmi.html'
    queryset = MaghaalaatPost.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-published']
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MaghaleMain, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = MaghaalaatPost.tags.all()
        return context


class MaghaleTags(ListView):
    model = MaghaalaatPost
    template_name = 'Blog/Blog-elmi.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MaghaalaatPost.objects.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs.get('tag_slug'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MaghaleTags, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tags'] = MaghaalaatPost.tags.all()
        return context


class MaghaleDetail(DetailView):
    model = MaghaalaatPost
    template_name = 'Blog/Blog-elmi-detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'maghaale'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'the_slug'
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["related_items"] = self.object.tags.similar_objects()[:3]
        return context
```

this is the error I get(I changed the debug to true in order to see the errors):
[image]

please help me I don't know what am I doing wrong and why I only have this issue online

Comment: The characters which make up your slug aren't valid for a URL. You can get details on valid characters here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/7109208/1199464

Comment: Its in persian. how do i validate that?

Comment: yeah, persian characters aren't valid for a URL. You'll need something that will convert non-ascii characters so that they can be used in a URL.