# Converting Persian Url Route to Persian Words on C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, converters, farsi

I made my routes to Persian , cause of that my Url route in StartUp config is like

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "HomeController",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Test" },
            pattern: $@"تست/خانه");
```

And it turns into this `https://localhost:44377/%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87/%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D9%87%20%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%DB%8C` in Browser address bar
and also when I try to get current request path in controller with
**Request.HttpContext.Request.Path**, it gives me the
`/%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87/%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D9%87%20%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%D` part that this is
**تست/خانه**
So I need help to convert this
`/%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87/%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D9%87%20%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%D`
to this => **تست/خانه**  in C# , MVC Core

Comment: Those characters need to be url escaped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url. When you get the request back, is the value correct in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is url encoded and you need to decode it.

```cs
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.HttpContext.Request.Path);
```