# Video intent href is picky about files

Tags: android, html, android-intent, href

I'm trying to create and index page for locally hosted movies, with href links that would open directly in MXplayer Pro in android.

I ran into a problem that **2nd link works great**, opens player/starts playing.
But **1st link** just opens Google Play for installation of the app. (this happens when intent url is **broken**)

So the funny part is that the only difference between the two links are the file paths. And there is no special character difference. Both files stream great on desktop player, also on android when I manually open then in MXplayer Pro.

So either my android devices (v4 and v10) don't like my taste in movies or someone did a very poor job at android.

```
    <li>  <a href="intent:http://192.168.0.64/media/So.You.Think.You.Can.Dance.S17E01.720p.WEB.h264-BAE[rarbg]/So.You.Think.You.Can.Dance.S17E01.720p.WEB.h264-BAE.mkv#Intent;package=com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro;end"> test1 </a> </li>

    <li>  <a href="intent:http://192.168.0.64/media/The.Humans.2021.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.800MB.x264-GalaxyRG[TGx]/The.Humans.2021.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.800MB.x264-GalaxyRG.mkv#Intent;package=com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro;end"> test2 </a> </li>
```

No JS please, just plain short html.

Comment: Have you tried URL-encoding your `http` URL? Have you tried creating a scrap Android app that creates an `Intent` with your desired values, then [called `toUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#toUri(int)) on it to see what you get? Also, please bear in mind that there are dozens upon dozens of Web browsers available for Android, and how they parse this may vary.

Comment: Based on answer below both urls are valid, (they also have the same characters)/same length, I tried 2 different browsers/2 android versions with same issue. So it points to an old OS bug.  I don't know about app development. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109143/what-characters-are-valid-in-a-url#7109208

Comment: "Based on answer below both urls are valid" -- quoting the answer that you linked to, "Also, some of these characters can only exist in very specific spots in a URI and outside of those spots must be url-encoded". And, if you read [the RFC that is linked to from that answer](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), you will notice that `:` tends to have special rules. So, have you tried percent-encoding your `http` URL?

Comment: Sure I gave it a go, but still opens gPlay.
```<a href="intent:http://192.168.0.64/media/So.You.Think.You.Can.Dance.S17E01.720p.WEB.h264-BAE%5Brarbg%5D/So.You.Think.You.Can.Dance.S17E01.720p.WEB.h264-BAE.mkv#Intent;package=com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro;end"> test </a>```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you cannot reliably use an `http` URL embedded in an `intent:` URL the way that you are.

In Kotlin, I assembled an `Intent` that would appear to match what you are looking for (using your first `http` URL):

```kotlin
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.64/media/The.Humans.2021.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.800MB.x264-GalaxyRG[TGx]/The.Humans.2021.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.800MB.x264-GalaxyRG.mkv"))

i.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro")
```

I then logged three different ways of creating a URL from that `Intent`:

```kotlin
Log.d("Foo", i.toUri(0))
Log.d("Foo", i.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))
Log.d("Foo", i.toUri(Intent.URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME))
```

`toUri(0)` says "give me as simple a URL as possible". `toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)` says "always give the URL the `intent:` scheme". `toUri(Intent.URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME)` says "always give the URL the `android-app:` scheme", which is new to Android 5.1.

Those give me the following URLs:

```
http://192.168.0.64/media/The.Humans.2021.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.800MB.x264-GalaxyRG[TGx]/The.Humans.2021.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.800MB.x264-GalaxyRG.mkv#Intent;package=com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro;end
intent://192.168.0.64/media/The.Humans.2021.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.800MB.x264-GalaxyRG[TGx]/The.Humans.2021.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.800MB.x264-GalaxyRG.mkv#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro;end
android-app://com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro/http/192.168.0.64/media/The.Humans.2021.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.800MB.x264-GalaxyRG[TGx]/The.Humans.2021.720p.AMZN.WEBRip.800MB.x264-GalaxyRG.mkv
```

So, try those and see if have better luck (noting again that the third one may only work on Android 5.1 and higher).

Comment: Cheers, 
1st is exact same I'm using, 
2nd has the same problem (opens gPlay), 
3rd is working! but it opens with android player, not in mxplayer (which is default), 
and gives no option to use with other, only to download. (even though we specified mxplayer in uri), does the 3rd kind work for you?

Comment: @VincentAlex: " 1st is exact same I'm using" -- not according to your question. You are using `intent:http://192.168.0.64...`. That is not the same as `http://192.168.0.64...`, as yours has `intent:` in front of it. "does the 3rd kind work for you?" -- I do not use MX Player and I do not have a plain HTTP server running on a local IP address. I agree that the behavior you describe is strange, as that runs counter to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME).

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2nd is exact same. Well if it's an OS bug then it's next to impossible to get a fix for it:(

Comment: @VincentAlex: "I meant 2nd is exact same" -- not according to your question. You have `intent:http://192.168.0.64...`. That is not the same as `intent://192.168.0.64...`, as you have `http:` before the IP address. Also, the one from Android has `;scheme=http` as part of the final stanza, and yours does not.

Comment: Oops, I missed that, tested with `;scheme=http` but same result. Somehow the file path upsets it, I will try to simplifying the name.